# macro() not doing a string replacement?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to use the macro() command for a context-insensitive string replacement, but this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

MACRO(TestMacro mystring)
  message(mystring)
endmacro()

TestMacro("hello world")

message("hello world")
```

outputs:

mystring
hello world

rather than

hello world
hello world

as I would expect. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dereferencing the macro parameter:

```
MACRO(TestMacro mystring)
  message(${mystring})
endmacro()
```

Also see the [Syntax Introduction](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/syntax.html).

Comment: Can that dereferenced parameter then be concatenated with other text? For example, what I'm really trying to do is create a variable called MyArgumentLibs for example. If I do

MACRO(TestMacro MyArgument)
  set(${MyArgument}Libs "something")
endmacro()

TestMacro(David)

is that doing what I'd expect? (i.e. the same as   set(DavidLibs "something")?

As you've described it, it seems more just like a normal function with a variable being passed than a real "macro" in the sense of a C-style #-macro where it actually just blindly replaces one string with another.

Comment: yes. Use something like exactly like what you've described: set(${value}_Blah "Value")

Comment: @Doug - so then when I want to get the value of DavidLibs, I'd have to do ${${MyArgument}Libs} ?

Comment: macro(Test key value)
  set(${key}_LIB ${value})
endmacro()
Test("Hello" "World")
message(${Hello_LIB}) --> "World". If you had a variable for the key, you could also go Test(${mykey} "world") message(${mykey}_LIB)

Comment: Ok, this works too:

macro(Test key)
  set(${key}_LIB "SomeValue")
  message(${${key}_LIB})
endmacro()

Test("HelloWorld")

The output is:

SomeValue

Thanks all.